# I dont know sql syntax for my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table

```
ID______credit________paydate
------------------------------
101_____10____________2012/01/01
101_____13____________2012/02/01
101_____8 ____________2012/03/01
101_____3 ____________2012/03/01
101_____22____________2012/05/01
..._____..____________..........
..._____..____________..........
999_____13____________2012/07/01
999_____38____________2012/08/01
```

I want to select all records for last 3 months(it is different last paydate for every ID) and where credit < 10

can someone help me with this??

thx and regards

Comment: Please rephrase your question to include more details. Also: you should first try and see what you can come up with, then post that here. We will not do your work for you but be happy to help you improve your solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If you show at least some effort, you probably won't get downvoted.

Comment: I already tried something, and the real table is more complex..
and I thought I missed something simple there, and my head already hurt -_-'

Answer (score 3):

You could use the DATEADD function to get the desired result:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  table
  WHERE paydate >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
        AND credit < 10
```

Comment: 'paydate' column isn't the current date, so it's impossible if i use getdate function.
and it is different paydate for every ID.